# VBA: In a fluctuating table how to change value in column 15 depending on value in column 16 (same table)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a newbie in Excel VBA, so need some help. Thanks in advance.

I've a table ('*Tabel26*') where the number rows change depending on the users choice.
All cells in each row has data validation (drop down), which works fine.
And my wish is that when the users selects a certain value/text from the dropdown menu in column 16, the value in column 15 change to a specific value + alert the user with a message.

With my present code - added at the end of this - it works fine when I have 1 row in the table. But doesn't work when 2 or more rows...
And I'm using *range().columns()* because the whole table can move down depending on a table above, which has the same features; add/delete rows. So I can't use *range('cell#')*.
And please don't be confused by the text, it's in Danish.

Maybe I need a count.rows and/or a loop, but not sure how.

CODE:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BEREGNING").Range("Tabel26").Columns(16).Value = "Skumringsrelæ (45 lx)" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BEREGNING").Range("Tabel26").Columns(15).Value = "4015"
        MsgBox (Space(5) & "Driftstiden er ændret til standardværdi for korrekt beregning:" & vbCrLf & Space(35) & "'365 dage x 11 timer'")
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to localise the action to a single cell. so ensure that your cell is a single cell in column 16  of the table then operate on the cell 1 column to the left relative

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Intersect(Target, _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BEREGNING").Range("Tabel26").Columns(16)) Is Nothing _ 
    And Target.Columns.Count = 1 _
    And Target.Rows.Count = 1 Then
    ' Target.Columns.Count = 1  and Target.Rows.Count = 1 guarantees that 
    ' just a single cell has changed

    If Target.Value = "Skumringsrelæ (45 lx)" Then
        Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = "4015"
        MsgBox (Space(5) & "Driftstiden er ændret til standardværdi for korrekt beregning:" & vbCrLf & Space(35) & "'365 dage x 11 timer'")
    End If
  End If
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that works!

However, this only changes the value to 4015 in column 15 once. 
How can I make sure that the this value can't be changed?

My initial code made sure of that, so I didn't think of describing that - sorry for that :)

Comment: Hi @JohanBirket-Smith - your english is a bit better than my Dansk so no need to apologise. so to be clear, if *any* cell in column 16 is changed to "Skum..." then *all* cells in column 15 should be set to "4015"?

Comment: Also "How can I make sure that the this value can't be changed" - not 100% sure what you need but you need to lock the cell, then protect the sheet. In the code where you want to modify the cell you need to unprotect the sheet, change the cell, then protect the sheet again https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.locked

Comment: LOL we can do in Danish if you want.

The change shall only happen for each row:
Table(26).Row(1).Column(16) = "Skum..." 
Then 
Table(26).Row(1).Column(15) = "4015" 
And so on; Row(2), Row(3) etc 

I can't lock cells in C(15), 'cause then the user can't select from the dropdown menu in C(15), which is possible when selecting something else than "Skum..." in C(16)

So to clarify:
The code should overrule and change the value to "4015" in C(15) at any time when the user selects "Skum..." in C(16).
And only change the value in the same row.

Does this give a better understanding? :)